# A limsup version of the Principle of Uniform Boundedness?

Tags: functional-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and let $\{f_\alpha\}$ be a net of continuous linear functionals satisfying $\limsup_{\alpha} | f_\alpha(x) | < \infty$ for each fixed $x \in X$. Is it true that

1. $\sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \limsup_{\alpha} | f_\alpha(x) | < \infty$  ?
2. $\limsup_\alpha \|f_\alpha\| < \infty$ ?

(Note: This question comes from a previous question of mine posted here which I removed because there was an error in the statement of the problem, pointed out by Daniel Fischer.)

I believe that if the directed set on which the net is indexed has a countable cofinal subset, then (1) can be proven by modifying the proof of PUB. I'm not sure about (2) or about the general case of (1).

Comment: Here is [link to the old thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873034/is-this-principle-of-uniform-boundedness) (which is deleted, so only 10k+ user, mods, OP are able to see it.) The only relevant thing there is comment by Daniel Fischer pointing out that we do not know whether $\{ x : \limsup \lvert f_\alpha(x)\rvert \leqslant n\}$ is closed, so the proof from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) cannot be simply copied without change.

Comment: Another possibly relevant information from the old thread is the definition of limit superior of a net of real numbers; just in case some people are not familiar with it: $\limsup_\alpha c_\alpha=\lim_{\alpha_0} \sup_{\alpha \geq \alpha_0} c_\alpha$.